# Export variables - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

code-

```
    const Test: React.FC <IProps> = ({text}) => 
    {
        const la = 4
        return(
            ...
        )
    };
```

How to export variable `la` from this fuction Test without using `export default`?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. The `la` variable is function scoped, and therefore cannot be exported. You can export the entire function (component) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `export`s must occur at the top level of a module. You have to do this:

```js
export const la = 4;

const Test: React.FC <IProps> = ({text}) => 
{
  return (
    ...
  )
};
```

`la` is still accessible by `Test` in this senario.

Comment: the la variable will change in time, is there any other way to export, Thanks

Comment: Hey @vishak, exporting a variable you expect to change probably isn't the right way to go about this if you want reactivity. However, that wasn't your question; if you want, you can edit your original post to clarify what you want to achieve.